# Does Build up factor actually make it worse to have shielding?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I'm having a little trouble understanding Build up factor in radioactive shielding equations. I learned that the equation for shielding with the Build up factor is:

$$I = I_0 \cdot B e^{-ux}$$

And I get that the B is there to account for the scattering of photons and the sort of redirecting them towards the source when they otherwise would have gone off in space.

- $MFP\,$ in the text refers to mean free path.

I was thinking about a point source of $^{137}\mathrm{Cs}$ in a room with concrete walls, and me with my meter 4 meters way from the point source with the wall in between us. When I calculate without B I get about a $60\%$ reduction. I expected when I finally found a B for a concrete wall that I would get maybe a $70\%$ reduction. But instead I see almost a 2x gain.

I got my B by reading through papers and old handbooks and I finally based it on two sources. One table shows B in mfp:

[image]

Another table I found shows the mfp for various concrete mixtures and gave about 11.8cm for ordinary concrete.

So now let's say I have an $11.8cm$ or 1mfp thick concrete wall and Cs-137 (through Barium) gives off Gamma rays at 660keV.  I think that makes my $B = 2.33$

If that's true it means that by having that concrete wall between me and my source I'm actually increasing the radiation dose I'll receive. Because if I plug those numbers into the formula I get about 139% of the dose.

Does this really happen?  Looking at that table if I increased my concrete thickness it would make it even worse.

I expected concrete shielding to make things better!

Comment: Is mfp mean free path ?

Comment: yes it is mean free path

Answer (score 0):

From the chart, at 1 mfp and 0.5 MeV, B is approximately 2.33 (actually lower for 0.66 MeV).

Since it is 1 mfp, the exponent term is $\exp(-1)=0.367$

Putting them together, I get
$$I/I_0 = 0.857$$

Did you do your exponential correctly?

edit: fix math